# why the docker did not load fonts when build in github actions

Tags: docker, github-actions

I have a simple docker image, and I want to load some fonts from docker image, this is the dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM alpine:3.18

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

WORKDIR /app
ENV ROCKET_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/ && mkdir -p /app/config/ && mkdir -p /root/.ssh
COPY ./config/font/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md.otf /usr/share/fonts/
RUN apk update && apk add fontconfig
CMD sh -c 'while true; do sleep 1; done'
```

in the build process, I copied a font into the container, after build and run in my local mac book pro, I can see the font loaded using this command:

```
/app # fc-list
/usr/share/fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Md.otf: Helvetica Neue LT Pro,HelveticaNeueLT Pro 65 Md:style=65 Medium,Regular
```

when I build this image by using github actions:

```
name: cv-render-k8s-pro

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up QEMU
      uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

    - name: Login to Docker Hub
      uses: docker/login-action@v2
      with:
        registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}

    - name: Build and push
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
      with:
        context: .
        file: Dockerfile
        push: true
        tags: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}/reddwarf-pro/cv-render:${{ github.sha }} 

    - name: deploy to cluster
      uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
      with: 
        config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
        command: set image --record deployment/cv-render-service cv-render-service=${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}/reddwarf-pro/cv-render:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro

    - name: verify deployment
      uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
      with:
        config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
        version: v1.21.0
        command: rollout status deployment/cv-render-service -n reddwarf-pro
```

I could not see the fonts loaded in the github actions builed image(It makes the app could not found the fonts):

```
/app # fc-list
/app #
```

Am I missing something? the different is the local using the macOS and remote github action using Ubuntu. what should I do to let the remote docker image load the fonts? I takes hours to figure out where is going wrong, did not find any clue about this issue.